# IDEA doesn't show all branches that could be merged

Tags: git, merge, intellij-idea, branch

I'd like to merge with Intellij IDEA (11.1.3) via the menu 'VCS -> Git -> Merge Changes'. But the desired branch (mergeRequest15) is missing. But why? Is it because it seems that this branch bases on another branch (mergeRequest14)?

**gitk --all shows:**

[image: gitk --all]
**IDEA shows:**

[image: IDEA merge branches]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the branch mergeRequest15 was already merged to master (you can see that in the history). Thus there is no need to merge.

Comment: Because mergeRequest14 and 15 have no differences?

Comment: If you would add another commit to the branch mergeRequest15, then you could merge again, because then there is one commit, which isn't already in master.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I was using RubyMine. I guess this applies to all JetBrains IDE's.